# Why does mov instruction to msg doesn't change the first character

Tags: assembly, x86-16, bootloader

```
; boot.asm
 mov ax, 0x07c0                 ; store 0x07c0 general purpose register
 mov ds, ax                     ; move ax value to segment pointer ds

 mov ah, 0x0                    ;
 mov al, 0x3                    ;
 int 0x10                       ;interrupt

 mov si, msg                    ;offset from data segment ds
 mov ah, 0x0E                   ;
 
 print_character_loop:          ;
 lodsb                          ;

 or al, al                      ;
 jz hang                        ;
 
 mov edx,9       ;message length
 mov ecx, msg   ;message to write
 
 mov    [msg],  dword 'Nuha'
 
 mov edx,8       ;message length
 mov ecx, msg    ;message to write

 int 0x10                       ;

 jmp print_character_loop       ;

 msg:                           ;
 db 'Zara Ali ', 10, 13, 0  ;

 hang:                          ;
 jmp hang                       ;

 times 510-($-$$) db 0          ;
 
 db 0x55                        ;
 db 0xAA                        ;
```

I am a complete newbie to assembly! I learnt a code which helps us change the content of the msg section which will be printed on QEMU
window. When I exeute the code, my code output is "Zuha Ali" instead
of "Nuha Ali".

Can someone explain me why this code is not working.

And also I have another question. I got this assembly language syntax
(or) code for a specific ISA from a website "Baby steps to create an
OS". Could someone tell me which ISA this belongs to and what is
specific name to denote this type of assembly language (Ex. Linux
Assembly, Microsoft Assembly).So finally, help me solve the 2
questions I have!

Comment: It does change the first character but you have already loaded it using `lodsb` by that time.

Comment: This is x86 16-bit assembly, for a legacy BIOS MBR bootloader, using BIOS int 10h calls.  (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/INT_10H).  It looks like NASM syntax, which is presumably what you used to assemble it so you could run QEMU on it. https://nasm.us/doc/.  QEMU makes it possible to attach a debugger: do that so you can single-step and see registers + memory change, and see what's going on.

Comment: @PeterCordes thank you for letting me  know my assembly is it possible I could change 16 bit to 32 bit assembly

Comment: Writing a bootloader is not a good excerice for a complete newbie.  Consider starting with writing DOS or Linux programs instead.

Comment: @Jester Then how could i change the first character in my program

Comment: If you want to print a different first character, overwrite it with `mov` earlier in your program, *before* you've loaded it.  Not in the middle of the loop after you've already loaded it.  Just like in any other language that works by copying values, not taking references.

Comment: @fuz Thank you for your recommendation, I amn't writing programs for linux any soon. but sure I will try out writing programs for DOS and run it on DOSBox for Windows. Actually I am trying to test out to build a basic os for better learning of computer architecture.

Comment: Is `mov edx,8       ;message length` / `mov ecx, msg` copy/pasted from a Linux example?   Those are the args that `int 0x10` / ah=0x0E looks for: it prints the one character in AL.  You never actually make an `int 0x80` Linux system call, which of course would only work in a Linux program, not a BIOS bootloader.  You can't randomly copy/paste code for different OSes into a program / bootloader.

Comment: @PeterCordes could you just modify my program and show me how to do this. I can't actually catch what you mean.  I am an newbie. Don't take me wrong

Comment: @PeterCordes yes most of the tutorials were pointing me at linux tutorials so I wanted to port it into x86 assembly(not linux x86). the tutorial was from https://www.tutorialspoint.com/assembly_programming/assembly_addressing_modes.htm .

Comment: Put `mov  [msg],  dword 'Nuha'` right after `mov ds,ax`.  That's right after the DS segment base is set correctly to match your implicit `org 0x0`, but before anything loads from `[msg]`.  Like I said, put the `mov` store earlier, before anything has loaded the data you're overwriting.  If you didn't already understand that, I'd suggest continuing to follow a tutorial to learn some basics.  https://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info has some links.

Comment: Asm isn't portable, especially not system calls.  If you're not writing a Linux program, don't expect that code to work anywhere else.  Also, that tutorial you linked is weird; the code block at the end is NASM syntax for 32-bit, but the code short blocks earlier with stuff like `ADD  BYTE_VALUE, 65` are in MASM / TASM syntax.  In NASM that would be `ADD  byte [BYTE_VALUE], 65`.  It takes a lot of work and experience to write good tutorials, and unfortunately the people with the skills to do so often don't take the time.  And sites like tutorialspoint have pretty mixed quality.

Comment: @Pranesh You might like to start with simple programs for DOS/Win which are easy to build, such as [Hello World](https://euroassembler.eu/eadoc/#HelloWorld) or other [skeletons](https://euroassembler.eu/objlib/). Then feel free to modify and enhance them for *better learning* of assembly language.